# Start reading from specific rows then loop within that row

Tags: python, csv

I have this csv file, here is an example of how the file looks like:

```
Number of students     80
Courses available      120
 
id     student number     coursesRegistered     scores
1      20001              5                     90     80     70     90     61
2      20002              4                     40     60     75     80
```

I would like to start reading rows starting from id 1 then store `student number` into a variable and also to do a `for` loop in range of the `courseRegistered` to obtain the score then store it into a `list`. How do i do that?

Comment: Did you try with [DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)?

Comment: The format of your file is not entirely clear. Are you displaying what the file looks like when it is loaded into a spreadsheet such as Excel or are you displaying the actual CSV file? If the latter, are those tab characters between the columns? It appears that each score occupies its own column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what the input format is (see my comment to your question). Assuming that each column is delimited by a comma in the actual CSV file and that each score is a separate column, then the following should succeed:

```
import csv


with open('test.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    for _ in range(4): f.readline() # skip first 4 lines
    rdr = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in rdr:
        student_number = int(row[1])
        courses_registered = int(row[2])
        scores = list(map(int, row[3:3+courses_registered]))
        print(student_number, scores)
```

Prints:

```
20001 [90, 80, 70, 90, 61]
20002 [40, 60, 75, 80]
```